# Permutations - counting

Tags: permutation

Four girls bought each a swimsuit , and they decided to share them . How many days are needed so that each girl will wear each swimsuit once ?

Comment: Does the order matter, or do you just want the possible top-5 groups? (I assume the order matters, but it’s worth asking.) // Please add the self-study tag, read its wiki, and say what progress you’ve made with this. We help with plenty of homework problems here, but we handle them differently from other questions. // Welcome to Cross Validated!

Comment: If order doesn't matter: $15\,504;$ if so, $1\,860\,480.$ What justification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order matters, there are 20 ways to choose 1st place, 19 ways to choose 2nd place, ..., 16 ways to choose 5th place: ${}_{20}P_5 = 20(19)\cdots(16) = 1\,860\,480.$ [Computation in R.]

```
prod(20:16)
[1] 1860480
```

If order does not matter: ${}_{20}C_5={20\choose 5} = \frac{20!}{5!\cdot15!} = 15\,504.$

```
choose(20, 5)
[1] 15504
```